# Calculating the ramification index of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

This is a subtask of *Problem 226* from Fernando Gouvea's book *$p$-adic numbers - An Introduction*.
In this book, the author mentions that **the ramification index $e = e(\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}_5)$ is exactly $1$** and I want to understand why this is true.

- As the ramification index is a divisor of $[\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}_5]=2$, we must have $e \in \{1,2\}$.

Let us assume $e = 2$. If we can find a contradiction, then $e$ must be $1$ and we are done.

- The ramification index $e$ is defined to be the unique positive integer such that $v(\mathbb{Q}_5^\times) = \frac{1}{e}\mathbb{Z}$ where $v$ denotes the valuation on $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt{2})$. If $e$ is $2$, then there must exist an $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}_5$ so that $v(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.
- Furthermore, the coefficient $b$ must be non-zero, otherwise $v(x)$ would be an integer which is a contradiction to $v(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.
- Calculating yields us $$\frac{1}{2} = v_5(x) = (a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})= a^2-2b^2$$ and would like to show that there can not exist such coefficients $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}_5$ in the first place. I can see that $a,b$ can not be both integers. But I was not able to extend my solution further.

Could someone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Your last calculation should come out as $a^2-2b^2$, not $a^2+2b^2$. Anyway, if either $a$ or $b$ is outside $\mathbf Z_5$ then show they both are with the same negative valuation. Then write $a=u/5^n$ and $b=v/5^n$ for units $u, v \in \mathbf Z_5^\times$. Clear denominators and reduce mod $5$ to get a contradiction. Now you know $a$ and $b$ are *both* in $\mathbf Z_5$. That is all I will say as a hint.

Comment: Let $a$ be outside of $\mathbb{Z}_5$, i.e. $v(a)<0$. Assume $v(a)\neq v(b)$. As $v(b) = v(2b)$, we obtain $0=\frac{1}{2} = v(a+2b)=\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$ which is a contradiction because $v(a)<0$. So $v(a) = v(b) < 0$.

Now write $a,b$ as you did. Then with your instructions I got $2u^2-4v^2=5^{2n}$. Reducing mod $5$ yields $0=2u^2-4v^2=2(u^2-2v^2)$. But I am not sure over which ring we are lying now. Is it $\mathbb{Z}_5/5\mathbb{Z}_5$? Is $5 \mathbb{Z}_5$ a prime/maximal ideal? If we are lying over an intregral domain, we must have $u^2=2v^2$. Does this help us?

Comment: I just found out that $5 \mathbb{Z}_5$ is the unique maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and that the residue field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_5$. But the equation $(\frac{u}{v})^2 = 2$ has no solutions over $\mathbb{F}_5$, as $2$ is a nonresidue mod $5$. Could you please check if my argument is correct?

Comment: Do you really have no other tools than what you were using? I would have argued that since $\Bbb F_5$ has no square root of $2$, the residue-field extension degree is two, so the ramification index must be one. Do you have $ef=n$, as a rule for finite extensions of complete fields?

Comment: @Lubin: I did not have that many tools as I just started to learn about ramification theory. But I heard about the rule $ef=n$. But I am not sure yet why the residue-field extension degree is 2. What are the residue fields of $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}_5$ in the first place?

Comment: Of $\Bbb Q_5(\sqrt2\,)$,it’s $\Bbb F_5(\sqrt2\,)=\Bbb F_{25}$; of $\Bbb Q_5$, it’s $\Bbb F_5$.